# JQueryMobile radio buttons with fieldcontain width issue on desktop

Tags: jquery, mobile, radio-button

I have 4 radio buttons horizontal and they look good on 320X300px (smartphone) but I want it to look good on a desktop or tablet.  How do I make the legend text wider or all fit in 2 columns.  I have tried using a grid but that seems to do nothing.  I suspect that I just need some CSS but I do not know what to do.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" >
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-ajax="true" class="row_b" >
<legend>This is a long question that gets wrapped around in a small space on a desktop but it would be great if it occupied more of the wasted space on the right.</legend>
<input type="radio" name="q2" title="Did not apply to me at all" id="q2_0" value="0" />
<label for="q2_0" style="width: 65px;">0</label>
<input type="radio" name="q2" title="Applied to me to some degree, or some of the time" id="q2_1" value="1" />
<label for="q2_1" style="width: 65px;">1</label>
<input type="radio" name="q2" title="Applied to me to a considerable degree, or a good part of time" id="q2_2" value="2" />
<label for="q2_2" style="width: 65px;">2</label>
<input type="radio" name="q2" title="Applied to me very much, or most of the time" id="q2_3" value="3" />
<label for="q2_3" style="width: 65px;">3</label>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you maybe show what you want it to look like? Wanting it to 'look good' is explicitly subjective. And is the question still of relevance to you?

Answer (score 0):

You could try two rows instead of columns.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6rCmY/1

I removed the `legend` and moved the text out of the `fieldset` and overrode the default CSS for the `.ui-btn` class as a child of `.row_b`

```
.row_b .ui-btn {
    text-align: center;
    width: 24.5%;
}
```

Or just move the text out of the fieldset and don't change the CSS at all...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GsUEz/1/